# Smartsheet API responses - how do I find them and use them?

Tags: c#

I am brand new to writing programs and want to use the Smartsheet API.  I can create objects in Smartsheet ok but how do I "grab" the responses that come back?  Where are they stored so I can use them in my code?  eg  the following code will call a list of sheets and associated info.  where is that info once called?

```
// Sample 1: Omit 'include' parameter and pagination parameters
        PaginatedResult<Sheet> sheets = ss.SheetResources.ListSheets(
          null,               // IEnumerable<SheetInclusion> includes
          null,               // PaginationParameters
          null);             // Nullable<DateTime> modifiedSince
```

Thanks in advance

Mick